# Can somebody please help me?

Tags: discussion

How do I delete this account? I went on Help and clicked "How do I delete my account?" But it was no use. Please help me with this because I have no use for this website anymore.

Comment: Why do you need to delete it? Just stop logging in.

Comment: It won't let me log out

Comment: Just stop using the website? I honestly can't see any circumstance where you still having an account logged in would affect anything, ever.

Comment: I will take your advoce